# How to convert char to int and then display it in hex format

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I am making a program in c in which I am getting data from serial device and I am storing it in buffer `char receivebuffer[100]` . when I display the contents of receivebuffer, the output shows `�` (Is this an ASCII format) . But the expected output is in hex format. How can i convert it in hex?

I also want to know that if I convert buffer to int, will the output be same. Please tell me how can I convert char buffer to int also?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
            printf("error %d from tcgetattr\n\n", errno);
            printf("Error Opening the device\n\n");
            exit(0);
            //error_message ("error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
            return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                    // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
            printf("error %d from tcsetattr\n\n", errno);
            printf("Error Opening the device\n\n");
            exit(0);
            //error_message ("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
            printf("error\n\n");
            printf("Error Opening the device\n\n");
                    exit(0);
            //error_message ("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
            return;
    }

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        printf("Error Opening the device\n\n");
        //error_message ("error %d setting term attributes", errno);
}

int main()
{
char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0)
{
    //error_message ("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname,         strerror (errno));
    printf("error");

}

set_interface_attribs (fd, B9600, 0);  // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
set_blocking (fd, 0);                // set no blocking

       // send 7 character greeting

usleep ((7 + 25) * 100);             // sleep enough to transmit the 7    plus
while(1)
{

char receivebuffer [100];
read (fd, receivebuffer, sizeof receivebuffer);  // read up to 100    characters if ready to read

printf("value of buffer is %s\n\n", receivebuffer);
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: And please post the code, because **convert** it makes absolutely no sense, is it display it?

Comment: sounds to me like a wrong conversion specifier in `printf()` so what about post a snippet?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am expecting data in hex format but it is �

Comment: @iharob yeah I want to display that in hex.

Comment: hexformat is as it says a "format" so thats no answer on his question.

Comment: So please post the code you are using right now to display.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, can you tell me how to post code.

Comment: Click edit and post it you need to indent each line with 4 spaces plus your indent.

Comment: @arjunsaini just post the code in your post and put for spaces in front of each line to indicate it as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the count of received bytes somewhere and use that in a for loop try it like this

```
char receivebuffer[100];
int  count;
int  i;
count = read (fd, receivebuffer, sizeof receivebuffer);  // read up to 100 characters if ready to read
for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
 {
    printf("0x%02X ", receivebuffer[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
        printf("\n");
 }
```

this `if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)` is just to print `8` bytes in a row, you can change or remove it, it helps inspecting the data though.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this:

```
printf("value of buffer is %s\n\n", receivebuffer);
```

with:

```
for (int tmpfoo = 0; receivebuffer[tmpfoo] != '\0'; tmpfoo++)
{
    printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", (int)receivebuffer[tmpfoo]);
}
```

If you want it just to be followed HEXvalue by HEXvalue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. %X is for hexadecimal? If I want it in decimal or like binary.?

Comment: For binary is no way provided sadly and for decimal simply use `%d` and note the cast to int.

Comment: Great.. you rock Thanks

Comment: Why `tmpfoo < sizeof(receivebuffer)`? and suppose the `receivebuffer` is not `nul` terminated which is almost sure. Isn't it much simpler to take the value returned by `read()` and print exactly that number of bytes? also suppose there is an embedded `'\0'` in the buffer? what? so if I could downvote twice I would.

Comment: @iharob then his whole code would be wrong. he used `%s` which lets me expect, as he didn't mention any errors, that the array is null terminated. Otherwise he would get trouble in a way that doesn't belong to his question and should be a new post. So I feel safe to expect it as null terminated.

Comment: @iharob: and the `tmpfoo < sizeof(receivebuffer)` just in case the input may overflow the array, so reading the `'\0'` 1 past the array bound would not lead to undefined behaving. Probably won't happen but it also isn't wrong.

Comment: @iharob to your eddit: " also suppose there is an embedded '\0' in the buffer? what?" again.... a array printed out by using `%s` probably won't have an embedded `'\0'`. So I'd love to downvote you for your ignorance if that wouldn't be unethical.

Comment: @Zaibis not necessarily the OP might have been lucky and in that case `for (i = 0 ; receivebuffer[i] != '\0' ; ++i)` would be enough if your statement is true, how would `tmpfoo > sizeof(receivebuffer)` be possible?

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to convert it. To display `char` as a hexadecimal number, use `%hhx` formatting in `printf`-group of functions.

Comment: I have done that but it is showing me warning : "format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’" ??

Comment: `%hhx` is for a single `char`, not for `char*`